# rails how to display data or retrieve values after find

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did a find on some model and got the following

```
>> @addy
=> [#<Address id: 3, street: "Some Street", houseNumber: nil, created_at: "2010-01-20 06:09:52", updated_at: "2010-01-20 06:09:52", address_id: 16>]
```

Now how do I retrieve the values?  what if i want the street?

`@addy.street` does not work netiher does `@addy[:street]`

what if i had a list of @addy's and wanted to loop through them to show street for each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@addy.first.street` should work, as it is list of Adress classes containing only one member.

For displaying each street for more adresses in list:

```
@addy.each do |address|
  puts address.street
end
```

or

```
list_of_streets = @addy.map { |address| address.street }
```

*Edit:*
When you have problem identifying what class you have, always check `object.class`. When you just use `object` in IRB, then you see output from `object.inspect`, which doesn't have to show class name or even can spoof some informations. You can also call `object.methods`, `object.public_methods`.

And remember that in Ruby some class is also an instance (of Class class). You can call `@addr.methods` to get instance methods and `@addr.class.methods` to get class methods.

*Edit2:*
In Rails `#find` can take as first parameter symbol, and if you pass `:first` of `:last`, then you'll get only one object. Same if you pass one integer (id of retrieved object). In other cases you get list as result, even if it contains only one object.